# Getting Too many arguments or Too few arguments on nested dict

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying to add type hints in a `dict` type which has multiple fields that bind functions to them.
e.g.

```
from typing import Dict, Callable, Any, Union

def fn():
  print("Hello World")

def fn2(name):
   print("goodbye world", name)

d = {
  "hello" : {
    "world": fn
  },
  "goodbye": {
    "world": fn2
  }
} # type: Dict[str, Dict[str, Union[Callable[[], None], Callable[[str], None]]]]

d["hello"]["world"]()
d["goodbye"]["world"]("john")
```

The problem I'm running to is whenever I try run `mypy` (v0.782) it throws error:

```
test2.py:17: error: Too few arguments
test2.py:18: error: Too many arguments
```

Clearly, I've passed the right argument as can be seen from the function definition and type hints. I'm clearly missing something for it to be throwing error.

However, the following works, so I suspect it has something to do with `Union` type in type hints.

```
from typing import Dict, Callable, Any, Union


def fn():
    print("Hello World")


d = {"hello": {"world": fn}}  # type: Dict[str, Dict[str, Callable[[], None]]]

d["hello"]["world"]()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me remind you that problems like the one described in the question arise when the following constraints are not taken into account when working with `Union`:

> Operations are valid for union types only if they are valid for **every** union item. This is why it’s often necessary to use an `isinstance()` check to first **narrow down** a union type to a non-union type. This also means that it’s recommended to avoid `union` types as function return types, since the caller may have to use `isinstance()` before doing anything interesting with the value.[1]

As a workaround, I could suggest using a single function with a optional argument.
I use `Protocol` to define callback type with optional argument that impossible to express using the `Callable[...]`

```
from typing import Protocol, Optional, Dict


class Fn(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, name: Optional[str] = None) -> None:
        ...


def fn(name: Optional[str] = None) -> None:
    if name is None:
        print("Hello World")
    else:
        print("goodbye world", name)


d: Dict[str, Dict[str, Fn]] = {
    "hello": {
        "world": fn
    },
    "goodbye": {
        "world": fn
    }
}

d["hello"]["world"]()
d["goodbye"]["world"]("john")
```

[1] https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#union-types

Comment: I like this however I can't help but feel it's a little restrictive. I wonder how it would look if I had not two but five functions with different size of parameters and return types?

Comment: Is there a limited set of keys for one function and also for others?

Comment: I can live with function being non-variadic. I'm just trying to wrap my head around on how the type would look if there were more than one property below `world` e.g. `{ "world": fn, "walk": fn2, "jump": fn3  }` in both `hello` and `goodbye` properties.

Comment: In such case you can use [TypedDict](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/) with a fixed set of keys